# Trying to wrap my head around 3 nested if statments

Tags: java, if-statement

Say I have an array of 5 strings and that related to that array is 3 arrays of integers all of the same size. e.g.`

```
String a[] = new String[5]
int x[] = new int[5]
int y[] = new int[5]

int z[] = new int[5]
```

so that a[0],x[0],y[0],z[0] are all related to the same thing.
I want to find out which index(es) in x[] hold the highest number. If more than one those has the same highest number then which of those has the highest number in y[] and if there is more than one with the same highest number which one would have the highest in z[](Its safe to assume that none would have the same max value in z[]

I've tried to explain as best I can..

This is the best if got it only checks the first 2 conditions

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{

if(x[i]>=maximum){
if(x[i]==maximum)
{
    if(y[i]>=maximum)
    {
        maximum=x[i];
        winner=a[i];
        maximum=y[i];
    }
}
else
{
    maximum=x[i];
    winner=teams[i];
    maximum=y[i];
    }
}
```

So this is my new code

```
static int compareValues(){
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        int max =0;
        int diff = x[i] - x[max];
        if (diff == 0){
            diff = y[i] - y[max];   
        }
        if (diff == 0){
            diff = z[i] - z[max];
        }
        if (diff > 0){
         max = i    
        }
}
return max;
```

}

Comment: Search through the arrays using a loop, put your if statements inside the loop and keep track of your highest value in a variable. Then compare using your if statements.    That should be the general logic behind what you are trying to accomplish.   It would be helpful to see what you have tried doing, as @BarbiePylon says above.

Comment: You need to move the `int max =0;` outside the loop. Other than that it should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `String[n]` is related to the `int[n]`s for each n then really you should compose them properly, make them `Comparable` and sort them.

```
class Thing implements Comparable<Thing> {

    final String a;
    final int x;
    final int y;
    final int z;

    public Thing(String a, int x, int y, int z) {
        this.a = a;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Thing o) {
        int diff = o.x - x;
        if (diff == 0) {
            diff = o.y - y;
        }
        if (diff == 0) {
            diff = o.z - z;
        }
        return diff;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + a + "," + x + "," + y + "," + z + "}";
    }
}

public static int max(Thing[] things) {
    // NB - This should really call compareTo.
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < things.length; i++) {
        int diff = things[i].x - things[max].x;
        if (diff == 0) {
            diff = things[i].y - things[max].y;
        }
        if (diff == 0) {
            diff = things[i].z - things[max].z;
        }
        if (diff > 0) {
            // Higher
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public void test() {
    Thing[] things = new Thing[6];
    things[0] = new Thing("Hello", 1, 2, 3);
    things[1] = new Thing("There", 1, 2, 4);
    things[2] = new Thing("Everyone", 0, 2, 3);
    things[3] = new Thing("How", 9, 0, 3);
    things[4] = new Thing("Are", 8, 9, 3);
    things[5] = new Thing("You", 7, 2, 3);
    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(things));
    System.out.println("Max: " + things[max(things)]);
    Arrays.sort(things);
    System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(things));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm only allowed use what we've covered in class so far so I cant use comparable.

Comment: @JerryMurphy - Then look at how I've implemented `compareTo` it does basically what you want.

Comment: @JerryMurphy - I've added a `max` method that may give you a better idea how to do it.

Comment: I know you've broken it down for me but putting in objects which we haven't covered yet is kinda stumping me. e.g. things[max].x - how does that compare to my solution? where I just have arrays, I'm sure it seems obvious to you lol

Comment: @JerryMurphy - `things[max].x` would be equivalent to `x[max]` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might be easier to understand:

```
static String compareValues() {
    // find the maximum in x
    int xMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (x[i] > xMax) {
            xMax = x[i];
        }
    }

    // find the maximum in y, but limited to the positions where x is maximal according to the calculation above
    int yMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (x[i] == xMax && y[i] > yMax) {
            yMax = y[i];
        }
    }

    // find the maximum in z, but limited to the positions where y is maximal according to the calculation above
    int zMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int iMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (y[i] == yMax && z[i] > zMax) {
            zMax = z[i];
            iMax = i; // record the maximum position
        }
    }

    return a[iMax];
}
```

I did not test the code, but I think that it should work.